# do-release-upgrade is failing silently. First steps to troubleshoot?

Tags: upgrade, 14.10, do-release-upgrade

When attempting to upgrade from 14.10 to 15.04 I'm running the following command.

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

The command is failing silently with no output on the command prompt.

What should be my first steps to troubleshoot this? Are there logs somewhere that I can check? I'm accustomed to more feedback from failing programs.

Edit 1: more info...

The command returns after about one second, and the exit code is 139, which indicates a segmentation fault.

Edit 2:

After running the following command

```
sudo strace -o do-release-upgrade.strace do-release-upgrade
```

You can find the strace output here:  http://pastebin.com/hb5zthbb

Comment: Really no output?

Comment: Yep really no output. The command returns after about one second. Exit code is 139. I'll add that info to the question.

Comment: Is there a mistake with `sudo apt-get upgrade`?

Comment: @David How did you get the exit code ?

Comment: @A.B.  Nope. `sudo apt-get upgrade` is working fine. I've used it several times since I noticed the problem.

Comment: @solsTiCe by running `echo $?` after attempting `sudo do-release-upgrade`

Comment: Post or link the output of `sudo strace -o do-release-upgrade.strace do-release-upgrade`

Comment: You could debug the program, it is Python. `sudo apt-get install python3-pudb` ;)

Comment: @A.B. strace output added. I am unfamiliar reading it.

Comment: @David What desktop environment are you using ?

Comment: @A.B. the pudb suggestion worked great! Using pudb3 I was able to view the error that failed to get printed to the screen. In an hour or two I will post the steps I took and the conclusion. If you want to write an answer to summarize, I'll give you the points. :)

Comment: @AUmarMukthar I am using KDE

Comment: Did you tried GUI upgrade . If not follow these instructions https://wiki.ubuntu.com/VividVervet/ReleaseNotes#Upgrading_from_Ubuntu_14.10

Comment: have you this file: `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`

Comment: @AUmarMukthar yes, I did try the GUI upgrade, with similar results.

Comment: @A.B. yes, I do have the `apt_pkg.cpython(...)` file. The error is occurring within that file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I have a somewhat unusual answer:

Since `do-release-upgrade` is written in Python and in your profile you mention that you know about Python, I've used a Python debugger and for me the program runs correctly.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pudb
```

Start the debugger with:

```
pudb3 $(which do-release-upgrade)
```

and localize the problem.

Then I looked at the `strace` [output](http://pastebin.com/hb5zthbb). That's the interesting part:

```
stat("/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=351400, ...}) = 0
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0x184e6} ---
```

---

I make a forecast:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-apt
```

Comment: Nice answer. This answers the question. Impressive forecast too. For me, the forecast does not solve the problem, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Do you have a solution?

Comment: I just added what I did as an answer. Unfortunately, no great solution.

Comment: `Reinstallation of python3-apt is not possible, it cannot be downloaded` =(

Answer (score 3):

Here are the debugging steps that I took.

1. Determined the failing program's return code

   ```
   sudo do-release-upgrade
   echo $?
   ```

   The code was `139`
2. Searched google for the return code to find out what it meant

   The code indicates a segmentation fault
3. Used `strace` to get an idea of where the error was happening

   ```
   sudo strace -o do-release-upgrade.strace do-release-upgrade
   ```

   This wrote the trace log into a file named `do-release-upgrade.strace`, and the log showed, at the bottom, the runtime file in which the failure occurred.
4. Ran the pudb3 debugger to debug `do-release-upgrade`

   If pudb3 is not installed yet.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install python3-pudb
   ```

   Run the pudb3 debugger

   ```
   sudo pudb3 /usr/bin/do-release-upgrade
   ```

   For those unfamiliar with debuggers, this allowed me to step through each execution point of the script.

   I quickly found the following error.

   ```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/usr/bin/do-release-upgrade", line 10, in <module>
       from UpdateManager.Core.MetaRelease import MetaReleaseCore
     File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/Core/MetaRelease.py", line 25, in <module>
       import apt
     File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
       import apt_pkg
   ImportError:
   /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so:
   undefined symbol: _ZN13pkgSrcRecords4StepEv
   ```

   Which lead me to the [corresponding ubuntu bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-apt/+bug/1385689)
5. Attempted removing and reinstalling the package indicated in the bug report

   First method

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-apt
   ```

   Second, more drastic method

   ```
   sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends python3-apt
   sudo apt-get install python3-apt
   ```

   Neither of these fixed the problem.

Conclusion:

I still find it odd that the error was not printed to stdout; normally, I expect it should be. This solution should not have required a debugger.

This is a bug in the binary package `python3-apt`. Without fixing the bug and rebuilding the package, this error is likely to remain.